# Why was this character unaffected by Dr. Strange's spell?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man-no-way-home

At the end of *[Spider-Man: No Way Home](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt10872600/)* (2021),

> Dr. Strange casts a spell to make everyone forget about Peter Parker and Spider-Man's identity. It emphatically affects everyone in the world, without exception.

We see the effects on the characters, except one:

> Peter Parker himself clearly has not suffered the memory loss that others have.

Perhaps I misunderstood or misremembered the ending. If there are no exceptions, how was he not affected?

Comment: Something something *One More Day*.

Comment: @Adamant There was some Rick and Morty levels of incompetent characters in this one that people will realize once the nostalgia wears off.  Strange included for doing it first place and Parker for not listening.  I honestly thought they were going to do "It's a Wonderful Life" with the number of fatalities Peter caused with his little request so he'd be grateful when it was all undone.  Boy was I wrong.  (Not saying I hated it but MCU Spider-Man should be way more depressed than he is because he messed up the worst in whole multiverse)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[From a transcript available on the internet](https://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=953&t=57457) which seems to match what I recall, the following is the discussion associated with the event you’re asking about:

> **Peter:** So cast a new spell. But this time, make everyone forget who Peter Parker is. Make everyone forget...me. 
>  **Strange:** No. 
> **Peter:** But it would work, right? 
> **Strange:** Yeah, it would work. But you got to understand, that would mean everyone, ***who knows and loves you we'd... we'd have no memory of you.*** It'll be as though ***you*** never existed. 
> **Peter:** I know. Do it. 
> **Strange:** Then go and say your goodbyes. You don't have long. 
> **Peter:** Thank you, sir. 
> **Strange:** Call me Stephen. 
> **Peter:** Thank you, Stephen. 
> **Strange:** Yeah... Still feels weird.

It’s clear from the context of the explanation that it only ever affects other parties: “We’d… we’d.” This event is presented in terms of “we/us” versus “you.”

There is no indication that the requesting party would be giving itself amnesia; the magic seems sufficiently robust and non-Mesphistopholean to resolve in the intended manner as both parties intended and understood. (In fact, this would have originally been the outcome of the first one too had it not been molested mid-casting.)

Comment: Ah, it was the exclusive "we".

Comment: To further support this answer, the dialogue “Do you remember the full moon party in Kamar-Taj. No. Exactly” clearly indicates that the target of the spell (assuming Dr Strange casted it on himself) is not affected the same way was others

Comment: @Wondercricket *assuming Dr Strange casted it on himself* Why would we assume that? The spell is apparently directed so it is up to the caster to decide.